# Verb with there

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I read the following line in an article by Chetan Bhagat in [The Times of India](https://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/The-underage-optimist/bjps-political-misstep-optics-of-the-rafale-defence-deal-is-terrible-no-matter-what-its-merits/) (emphasis mine):

> Was there wrongdoing? Well, **there’s all kind of versions**. Proving legal wrongdoing is an uphill task (like any previous alleged scam). However, there are some things that happened here that don’t seem right.

As "all kind of versions" is plural, I thought it should be "There are ...".
Can anyone please assert?

Comment: Please identify the exact source. Ideally you should link to the online version of the newspaper. If that is not possible then tell us exactly where you saw this.

Comment: Paragraph 3. Second sentence. https://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/The-underage-optimist/bjps-political-misstep-optics-of-the-rafale-defence-deal-is-terrible-no-matter-what-its-merits/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. "All kinds of versions" is plural.

It should be

> **there are** all kinds of versions

The mistake of using "there's" with a plural noun is quite common, even for native speakers. Sometimes "there are" is pronounced as a contraction, like "there're", but it is almost never written.

Comment: Very common! Expressions such as **There's lots of people outside...** and **There's massives of food piled up.....** have become almost idiomatic.